# To calculate the sum of numbers in a list by Python

Tags: python

My data

```
466.67
465.56
464.44
463.33
462.22
461.11
460.00
458.89
...
```

I run in Python

```
sum(/tmp/1,0)
```

I get an error.

**How can you calculate the sum of the values by Python?**

Comment: Are these values stored in the array named `tmp` mentioned above?

Comment: This question is way too localized.  It should be more general.  Such as How do I sum a series of values in Python?

Comment: @S.Lott: I added the original error message. I also addded my thoughts about the problem in hand. --- I am still not completely sure that Unknown's answer is the most Pythonic one.

Comment: your edit is excessive. it turns an ordinary question into pointless rant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
sum(float(i) for i in open('/tmp/1.0'))
```

Comment: Why do you use `.read().split()` in your answer? --- Your code works without them.

Comment: How do you read the part `float(i) for`. This is my first time that I see a function before a for -loop.

Comment: How did you deduce that you need to have `float(i) before the for -loop?

Comment: @ SilentGhost: Where is the explanation of the syntax in manual? --- I could not find it in Python's help(), nor in the online manual.

Comment: I accept this answer because I see that it is less implicit to use `float(i)` inside `sum` than the use of `map`.

Comment: @SilentGhost: Thank you for the link and your answer! --- I see that your way of using `generator expression` is much clearer than the use of `map` -function.

Answer (score 13):

```
f=open('/tmp/1')
print sum(map(float,f))
```

Comment: Please, see my reply to your initial answer.

Comment: Why isn't this using the sum method like SilentGhost's answer?

Comment: Why is this question more Pythonic than SilentGhost's one? --- In my opinion, the use of the function `map` is rather implicit.

Comment: @ I ask everybody. --- I tend to accept answers which get the vote of the majority.

Comment: well, apparently it's not the best strategy. Accepted answers regardless of their correctness tend to get higher vote. Seriously, how many of the voters saw that tiny `pythonic` tag do you think?